# MySQL to MSSQL data types transfer

Tags: mysql, sql-server, transfer

I'm transferring a small database from MySQL to MSSQL.

the current MySQL example declaration:
*(Keys and Not Null are intentionally skipped)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
    `id` bigint(20),
    `version` int(10),
    `user_id` tinyint(3) unsigned, /*less then 100*/
    `date_crated` int(11), /*unix time like 1334736752 */
    `image_content` blob,
    `xml_content` longtext /*xml with non english texts, 5000+ character*/
)
```

And my MSSQL variant:

```
CREATE TABLE [my_table](
    [id] bigint,
    [version] int,
    [user_id] tinyint, 
    [date_crated] int,
    [image_content] varbinary(MAX),
    [xml_content] nvarchar(MAX)
 )
```

I m not confident about the last three...
Is there any potential data lost this way ?

Comment: Why are you using integers, rather than temporal types, to store dates?

Comment: @eggyal the date is stored as unix time for localization support,
can you give an example for 'temporary types' and why it is better?

Comment: Not *temporary* types; *temporal* types (as in, relating to time).  `TIMESTAMP` for example, stores the data as "*unix time*" but MySQL will be aware of the value's meaning - therefore it will automatically adjust input/output for the session's [`time_zone`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me except for `date_created` and `version`: I'd go for `bigint` (64 bit, UNIX timestamp was widened from 32 bit to 64 bit) or `timestamp` --- MSSQL int is 4 Byte (32 bit). You should also check if you need 64 bit integers for `version` too.

Comment: so `bigint` for ID columns on (possibly huge) entities is the way to go?

Comment: Well depends on the data stored in ID in MySQL --- we can only speculate based on the MySQL schema you provided.